# Posterior Distribution of a Normal Sample using Jeffreys Prior with a Known Parameter

Tags: bayesian, normal-distribution, prior, posterior, jeffreys-prior

Suppose I have a sample of $x_1, x_2, ... x_n$, where $X \sim N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, for some known $\sigma^2$, and that $\mu$ is defined only in $\mu \in [0, b]$, for some finite constant $b$.

It then follows from [these notes](https://www2.stat.duke.edu/courses/Fall11/sta114/jeffreys.pdf) that the Jeffreys Prior, that $\xi_J(\mu) = \frac{c}{\sigma}$, integrating with known bounds of $\mu$ would yield $\xi_J(\mu) = \frac{1}{b}$.

Then it follows the posterior distribution would be
$\xi_J(\mu|x) = c L(\mu;x)\xi(\mu)$ where $c$ is a constant, and $L$ is the likelihood function of the Normal Distribution.

$\xi_J(\mu|x) = c L(\mu;x)\xi(\mu)$

$\xi_J(\mu|x) = \frac{c}{b(2\pi)^{n/2}\sigma^n}\exp[\frac{-\sum_{i=1}^{n}(X_i-\mu)^2]}{2\sigma^2}]$

The question now comes, can the posterior distribution be simplified? It does look like a Normal distribution, but where I am stumped is that there is a sigma notation. Are there any tricks to map it to the parameters of $N(\mu_0, \sigma_0)$ for some $(\mu_0, \sigma_0)$?

Comment: Hint: find the classic resolution for the posterior in the unconstrained case and apply the truncation to $(0,b)$ only then.

Comment: Writing out the sum for the case $n=2$ and doing the (easy) algebra should make the result obvious.